# Python for loop is not iterating,

Tags: python, for-loop

The iteration only run once, Below is the code I am trying to run,

```
def heat_coeff(gas,Nu,d):
    """Calculate heat transfer (at interior tube wall)"""
    mass = gas *100
    diff = mass * 2
    for i in d:
        U = 4.*diff*Nu / (i*i)
        return U

heat_coeff(10,4, [1,2,3])
```

Comment: `return` terminates the function

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: From the comments I can infer that you want to return a list, but nothing in your code will have that effect. Please take some time to read more about lists and learn how to use them, also read about list comprehensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `return` *inside* the loop, and put it *outside*. Otherwise you'd be exiting prematurely!

```
for i in d:
    U = 4 * diff * Nu / (i*i)
return U
```

There's another bug, though. What do you intend to do with the `U` inside the loop? you have to *update* it on each iteration, otherwise you'll only get the value of the last iteration.

**EDIT:**

Now that you've explained what you need in the comments (and this should have been in the question, to begin with), this is what you intended to do:

```
def heat_coeff(gas, Nu, d):
    mass = gas * 100
    diff = mass * 2
    return [4.0 * diff * Nu / (i*i) for i in d]
```

For example:

```
heat_coeff(10, 4, [1, 2, 3])
=> [32000.0, 8000.0, 3555.5555555555557]
```

Comment: I moved the return outside the loop and still couldn't get an array as the output.

Comment: Wait, _what_? how do you expect to get an array, if you haven't even declared it? what exactly is this function supposed to return?

Comment: @David Do you mean that each value of `U` should be an element of a new array? If so, you need to learn about "list  comprehensions"

Comment: The function is suppose to return U, which should have different values based on my d [1,2,3]. I want the U to be an array of U at the three different values of d

Comment: @David Then yes, you need to do that with a list comprehension.